# Rotate cube in two direction not working in Unity

Tags: rotation, unity-game-engine, axis, cube, angle

First thing, i want to rotate block left-right , right-left, top-bottom and bottom-top.

See figure-1 one cube is their and all axis. when i rotate top to bottom (black arrow) cube z angle changed (red arrow) and get figure-2 this all work fine.

see figure-2 after that i move left to right rotate (black arrow) cube x angle change but at this time rotation is wrong beacuse of after first rotation all axis changed. and result is figure-3.

see figure 3 i am getting this position and movement (see red arrow), but i want exact figure-4 that not getting me.

please help me solve this.

Thnx

check code file https://www.dropbox.com/s/91i0z0p5dnabq6r/rotation.js

also check file https://www.dropbox.com/s/j8i269ftsdsxz7a/VID_20140129_161704.mp4

( in this video cube movement show and also show you true rotation and wrong rotation)

[image]

Comment: if you don't post any code, we can't really help...

Comment: @StevenMills check my code file and give me reply

Comment: [Gimbal Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)? Try to avoid Euler angles by using quaternions only

Comment: i used that but not working properly.